# Splitting out xml result into dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Hope someone can help - I'm new to js/jQuery so I'm hoping it's something really simple I'm missing here.

I'm trying to populate a dropdownlist with the xml result from below. The parseXML function works great and the **result.push(valueid + "," + value)** leaves me with the following:

1,Service

2,Breakdown

How do I get this into a dropdownlist please? Using the below, I get the error "**Object doesn't support property or method 'split'**"

Many thanks

leddy

```
function testFunction() {

var jobresults = "<resultset morerecords='0'> " +
                        "<result> " +
                            "<itt_jobtypeid>1</itt_jobtypeid> " +
                            "<itt_name>Service</itt_name> " +
                        "</result> " +
                    "<result> " +
                        "<itt_jobtypeid>2</itt_jobtypeid> " +
                            "<itt_name>Breakdown</itt_name> " +
                        "</result> " +
                    "</resultset> ";

    var xml = parseXML(jobresults);

    var jobid = xml.getElementsByTagName("itt_jobtypeid");
    var jobname = xml.getElementsByTagName("itt_name");
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < jobid.length; i++) {
        var valueid = jobid[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var value = jobname[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        // add longitude value to "result" array
        result.push(valueid + "," + value);
    }

    var jobtype = $("#ddlJobType");

    $.each(result, function () {
        var arr = result.split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            jobtype.append($("<option />").val(arr[0]).text(arr[1]));
        }
    });   

}

function parseXML(text) {
    if (window.DOMParser) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        doc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
    }
    else { // Internet Explorer
        doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        doc.async = "false";
        doc.loadXML(text);
    }
    return doc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be simpler and cleaner if you optimize data structure for `result` array. Push an object with value and label so that you can simply use `attr` method directly after:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jobid.length; i++) {
    var valueid = jobid[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var value = jobname[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    // add longitude value to "result" array
    result.push({value: valueid, label: value});
}

var jobtype = $("#ddlJobType");

$.each(result, function (i, obj) {
    $('<option>').attr(obj).appendTo(jobtype);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/. The callback function gets each jobtype as parameter to the function.
Try changing the code to:

```
$.each(result, function (idx, value) {
    var arr = value.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        jobtype.append($("<option />").val(arr[0]).text(arr[1]));
    }
});
```